# What does "Error: Failed to find a way to create transactions" in simplewallet mean?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-fees

I get this error message when I try to send the full balance from monero-wallet-cli / simplewallet. Reducing the amount to cover the fees makes the error message go away.

So does this simply mean "Your remaining balance is not enough to cover the fees" or is there something else wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means exacly: 
"not enough money to transfer, available only xx.xx0000000000, transaction amount xx.xx0000000000 = xx.xx0000000000 + 0.040000000000 (fee)"

You trying send everything? If you have 10xmr and want to send everything you must send 9.6 to cover the fee.

Check wallet log file to find out first what the fee is, because it depends on mixings and amount being sent.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks. Would be great with a different type of error message then.

Answer (score 3):

The `sweep_all` command might work better for you...

Comment: Just reducing the send amount by 0.01 to cover the fees made the transaction go through. My question is what the error message means.